# Is it safe to hold only unsafe.Pointer on the first element of slice and no refs to that slice itself?

Tags: go, slice, unsafe

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
    "runtime"
)

func getPoi() unsafe.Pointer {
    var a = []int{1, 2, 3}
    return unsafe.Pointer(&a[0])
}

func main() {
    p := getPoi()
    runtime.GC()
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground %v\n", *(*int)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(p)+8)))
}
```

output: 3

https://play.golang.org/p/-OQl7KeL9a

Just examining abilities of unsafe pointers, trying to minimize memory overhead of slice structure (12 byte)

I wonder if this example correct or not.
And if not, what will go wrong exactly after such actions. if it's not correct, why the value is still available even after an explicit call to GC ?
Is there any aproach to reach minimum overhead on storage like 'slice of slices', as it would be in C (just array of pointers to allocated arrays, when overhead on each row is sizeof(int*)).

Comment: Probably you'd better minimize memory consumption by using int32 or even int16 than saving 2*8 byte by replacing a slice header with an unsafe.Pointer. For the slice-of-slice-of-slice case: Make one slice and do the index calculation yourself (see e.g. package image).

Comment: Also keep in mind that int is 4 bytes on 32bit systems and 8 bytes on 64bit, so if you gonna use pointers, make sure you use a sized int. Also if performance of slices is really important, use Go from git (or wait for 1.7), there have been major performance improvements.

Comment: yep, all remarks are sensible, but in some cases they are ineligible. for example, if i have dynamic table of records, it would be not convenient to operate with solid slice using index calculations, deleting rows from solid slice would be very heavy. in this case, i think, slice of slices is most preferable approach.

Comment: sure, i should use []int32 and unsafe.Sizeof instead of direct value 8 (and Printf), but it is just example to illustrate the question

Comment: I don't see this defined in any way. While holding a pointer to a value allocated in a slice appears to prevent the GC of the array, it may not always be the case (for example if they implement collection for unreachable portions of slices). The unsafe.Pointer is only keeping a reference to the single int value, not the entire array.

Comment: The fact that the result of slice indexing is addressable, per the spec, *without* using `unsafe`, *might* argue that this is actually legit, or could be made so. If `getPoi` returned `&a[0]` instead of an `unsafe.Pointer` I believe that `a` would be required to be kept alive.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, that by coincidence, this will work out for you but I would regard it as unsafe and unsupported. The problem is, if the slice grows beyond it's capacity and needs to be reallocated, what happens to your pointer? Really if you want to optimize performance, you should be using an array. On top of it's performance being inherently better and it's memory footprint being smaller, this operation would always be safe.

Also, just generally speaking I see people doing all kinds of stupid things to try and improve performance when their design is inherently poor (like using dynamic arrays or linked lists for no reason). If you need the dynamic growth of a slice then an array isn't really an option (and using that pointer is also most likely unsafe) but in many cases developers just fail to size their collection appropriately out of idk, laziness? I assume your example is contrived but in such a scenario you have no reason to ever use a slice since your collections size is known at compile time. Even if it weren't, often times the size can be determined during runtime in advance of the allocation and people just fail to do it for the convenience of using abstracted dynamically sized collections.

Comment: btw, i think, array is a good option, becouse if compared to some kind of lists (allowing easy growth without reallocs), it gives best memory usage and scan performance. i think, it is very specific question, what kind of collection to use, depending on specific conditions.

Comment: also, this example will never be the basis of some real solution, ofcourse. i trying such extreme cases to better understand language behaviour and relations